# How to get names of friends that were picked in Facebook web dialog?

Tags: android, facebook, bundle

This is an example dialog for making app request. Is there any way to get friend names from bundle?

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", "Send Request");

    WebDialog.Builder builder = new WebDialog.Builder(CreateVoteActivity.this, Session.getActiveSession(),
            "apprequests", parameters);

    builder.setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
            if (error != null){
                if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException){
                    Toast.makeText(CreateVoteActivity.this, "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(CreateVoteActivity.this,"Network Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else{

                final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                if (requestId != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateVoteActivity.this,"Request sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateVoteActivity.this,"Request cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    WebDialog webDialog = builder.build();
    webDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I used this:

http://www.quora.com/Android-Development/How-can-one-convert-an-Android-Bundle-to-a-String-for-debugging-purposes

to get my bundle keys and there is only "to" and "request" so I guess its impossible to get picked names from dialog...